# Can you count columns from a certain row inside a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently trying to count all filled columns inside a certain row. Would that be possible?

E.g.:

[image]

I want to start counting from the 3th and only the columns that are filled.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data (both as **TEXT** we can copy/paste and execute and not images that we can hardly see); a description of the logic you want to implement; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with your solution; and the expected output for that sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `NVL2` function to check if a column is "filled" (non-`NULL`) or not "filled" (`NULL`) and then add up the values for each column:

```sql
SELECT NVL2(column3, 1, 0)
       + NVL2(column4, 1, 0)
       + NVL2(column5, 1, 0)
       + NVL2(column6, 1, 0)
       + NVL2(column7, 1, 0)
       -- ...
       + NVL2(column42, 1, 0) AS number_of_non_null_columns
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  column1,
  column2,
  column3,
  column4,
  column5,
  column6,
  column7,
  /* ... */
  column42
) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, /* ... */ 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NULL, 1, /* ... */ 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, NULL, NULL, /* ... */ 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, /* ... */ NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NUMBER_OF_NON_NULL_COLUMNS |
> | --- |
> | 6 |
> | 5 |
> | 4 |
> | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=281da29a2870f123ac191c03886b19f1)*